# Extending Types by Subclassing in Python

Tags: python

This is extracted from Learning Python 4th edition. Its function is to subclass set using list. But I don't understand line 5 `list.__init__([])`, please help. The code works even when I commented out this line of code. Why?

```
### file: setsubclass.py

class Set(list):
    def __init__(self, value = []):      # Constructor
        list.__init__([])                # Customizes list 
        self.concat(value)               # Copies mutable defaults

    def intersect(self, other):          # other is any sequence
        res = []                         # self is the subject
        for x in self:
            if x in other:               # Pick common items
                res.append(x)
        return Set(res)                  # Return a new Set

    def union(self, other):              # other is any sequence
        res = Set(self)                  # Copy me and my list
        res.concat(other)
        return res

    def concat(self, value):             # value: list, Set . . .
        for x in value:                  # Removes duplicates
            if not x in self:
                self.append(x)

    def __and__(self, other): return self.intersect(other)
    def __or__(self, other):  return self.union(other)
    def __repr__(self):       return 'Set:' + list.__repr__(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Set([1,3,5,7])
    y = Set([2,1,4,5,6])
    print(x, y, len(x))
    print(x.intersect(y), y.union(x))
    print(x & y, x | y)
    x.reverse(); print(x)
    x
```

Comment: Please don't use `value=[]` as a default value, it will work in this specific case but is a very bad habit to get into as it will often introduce subtle bugs. Using `value=()` as the default argument would be safe and doesn't require any other code changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the book contains an error. I've submitted an errata to O'Reilly books, which you can read along with the authors response on [this page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920028154) (search for 982). Here's a small snippet of his response:

> This code line has apparently been present in the book since the 2nd Edition (of 2003--10 years ago!), and has gone unremarked by hundreds of thousands of readers until now

The line `list.__init__([])` is *missing an argument*, and commenting it out makes no difference whatsoever, except speeding up your program slightly. Here's the corrected line:

```
        list.__init__(self, [])
```

When calling methods that are not static methods or class methods directly on class objects, the normally implicit first argument `self` must be provided explicitly. If the line is corrected like this it would follow the good practice that Antonis talks about in his answer. Another way to correct the line would be by using `super`, which again makes the `self` argument implicit.

```
        super(Set, self).__init__([])
```

The code in the book provides a *different* empty list (`[]`) as the `self` argument, which causes *that* list to be initialized over again, whereupon it is quickly garbage collected. In other words, the whole line is dead code.

To verify that the original line has no effect is easy: temporarily change `[]` in `list.__init__([])` to a non-empty list and observe that the resulting `Set` instance doesn't contain those elements. Then insert `self` as the first argument, and observe that the items in the list are now added to the `Set` instance.

Comment: I guess it is left blank for customization, since it is annotated "Customizes list".

Comment: @yanglifu90 That refers to the fact that the list always starts out as empty, and any initial values are added afterwards one by one in `self.concat`. I've no issues with it being blank, and that's as it should be. The last paragraph deals with verifying that the original code in fact has *no effect*. I didn't mean to imply that the list ougth to be non-empty.

Comment: `list.__init__(self)` on its own would work just as well to call the base initializer.

Comment: @Duncan Indeed, but [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Besides, it better illustrates what was wrong with the original line -- not a *wrong* argument, but a *missing* argument.

Comment: @yanglifu90 I've submitted an errata to O'Reilly and received a response from the author. See the update at the top of my answer.

Comment: Quoth Lutz: "Interestingly, this code line has been present in the book since the 2nd Edition (of 2003 — 10 years ago), and has gone unremarked by hundreds of thousands of readers until now." Is that an attempt at an argument? "Sure it's wrong, but no one bothered to complain until now".

Answer (score 4):

You mean this line?

```
    list.__init__([])
```

When you override the `__init__` method of any type, it's good practice to always call the inherited `__init__` method; that is, the `__init__` method of the base class. This way you perform initialization of the parent class, and add initialization code specific to the child class.

You should follow this practice even if you are confident that the `__init__` of the parent does nothing, in order to ensure compatibility with future versions.

**Update:** As explained by Lauritz in another answer, the line

```
    list.__init__([])
```

is wrong. See his answer and the other answers for more.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where can I find the class `list`'s definition? I want to find out what its `__init__` really do.

Comment: I don't know. The `list` class is an essential Python built-in type and I'm confident it's written in C. In order to see its implementation, you'd have to search the Python sources. Even if you know C, you probably don't want to do this until you become more experienced in Python.

Comment: By the way, contrary to what the comment inside your pasted code says, `__init__` is not a constructor. The constructor is `__new__` (but this is more advanced, and most of the time you don't need to use it). When `__init__` is called, the object is already constructed.

Comment: Well, I'd better skip this, it is a slot wrapper(`<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'list' objects>`). Too advanced.

Answer (score 3):

You mean `list.__init__([])`?

It calls the base initializer from the subclass initializer. Your subclass has *replaced* the base class initializer with its own.

In this case commenting that out happens to work because the unbound initializer was called with an empty list instead of `self` and is thus a no-op. This is an error on behalf of the authors, most likely.

But it is a good idea generally to make sure the base class has run its initialization code when you subclass. That way all internal data structures the base class methods rely on have been set up correctly.

Comment: And yes, I initially missed that `list.__init__` is unbound. Oops. But the error appears to have been copied to at least [one other book now](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18308417).

Answer (score 1):

This line is like creating an `__init__` constructor in Set class which calls its base class constructor.

You might have already seen this:

```
class Set(list):
...   
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Set, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
        # do something additional here
```