# Why inserting __init__() of superclass in this case?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I am now reading HeadFirstPython and there is an example about class.

```
>>> class NamedList(list):
>>>    def __init__(self, a_name):
>>>        list.__init__([])
>>>        self.name = a_name
```

In this case why is the statement `list.__init__([])` used?
And also cannot understand why it is including the empty `[]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending Types by Subclassing in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988480/extending-types-by-subclassing-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Normally**, because it is *good practice* to call the initializer of the class you are inheriting from.

However, the author seems to have substituted `self` for an empty list; I'd have used one of:

```
super(NamedList, self).__init__()
super(NamedList, self).__init__([])
```

or at the very least provided an explicit `self` argument:

```
list.__init__(self)
```

In this case, you are subclassing `list`; it's initializer takes a initial list of elements to  start with, but your own initializer only takes `a_name`, so the superclass initializer is passed an explicit empty list.

The `list.__init__()` method does little more than clear and extend; it is the equivalent of `self.clear(); self.extend(argument)`, resetting it's size and making it re-usable in case `__init__()` is called multiple times.

Passing in a new list object to the `list` initializer makes the call entirely useless and a no-op; that's an error that must've slipped by the technical review.

Comment: But why writing empty '[]' in the __init__ method? How about putting 'self'?

Comment: Actually, that is a good point. The correct way to call it would be `list.__init__(self, [])`..

Comment: You overlooked this in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17988480/566644) too.

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow: I looked for the book title and class name.. Voted to close as dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you misunderstood. I meant that you overlooked the same error (missing `self`) in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988562/566644) to the question I linked to.

Comment: Ah, right! Still a dupe there; I'll have to fix that answer though. And I **knew** this looked familiar..

Answer (score 1):

The code from the book contains an error. The line `list.__init__([])` is *missing an argument*, and commenting it out makes no difference whatsoever, except speeding up your program slightly.

I almost couldn't believe it when I read your question, because I recently answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989334/566644) about code from another book ("Learning Python") that contains *exactly the same error*.

Here's the corrected line:

```
        list.__init__(self, [])
```

When calling methods (that are not static methods or class methods) directly on class objects, the normally implicit first argument `self` must be provided explicitly. Another way to correct the line would be by using `super`, which makes the `self` argument implicit.

```
        super(NamedList, self).__init__([])
```

The `[]` argument is unnecessary in either case, but it's a good habit to write explicit code, and in this case it communicates that we really want the list to be empty.

What the code in the book does is to provide an empty list (`[]`) as the `self` argument. This causes *that* list to be initialized (over again), after which it is soon garbage collected since no reference to it is kept anywhere. In other words, the whole line is dead code.

To verify that the original line has no effect is easy: temporarily change `[]` in `list.__init__([])` to a non-empty list and observe that the resulting `NamedList` instance doesn't contain those elements. Then insert `self` as the first argument, and observe that the items in the list are now added to the `NamedList` instance.